# Why did I get Permission denied after I used "sudo" keyword?

Tags: python, linux, terminal, nltk, sudo

I want to install NLTK(natural language toolkit) on my mac, but when I used
`sudo curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -o - | python`
on my terminal, after I enter the password; the terminal says

error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-2365.pth'
```

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/
```

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If the
installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in
as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have administrative
access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation
directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH environment
variable.

For information on other options, you may wish to consult the
documentation at:

https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/easy_install.html

Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.

Something went wrong during the installation.
See the error message above.

Could anyone please tell me how to fix it, I really need this toolkit to finish my work.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You need a second sudo, you need to also run python with `sudo python`

```
sudo curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -o - | sudo python
```

Comment: yes..that i am trying to find out.But saved my time(not much valuable) ;)

Comment: Instead of using `sudo` twice, can't we just do `sudo su`?

Comment: not unless you run that command first and then curl but then you are in a root shell.

Comment: Oh, understood. 2 line answer for a 40 line question, impressive, very impressive.

Comment: Just for the record, the first sudo is **not** necessary.  //curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -o - | sudo python// will do.

Comment: @liangweiguo, no prob,  you are piping the output from curl to python but without the  other sudo python  you are just running `python ..`  which gives you the error, it is a little confusing but you just have to consider both commands to be completely separate as if you executed each separately. As tink  pointed out you don't need sudo to run the curl command but in this case in makes no difference